# 4x4 transformation matrix - how to find out center of rotation?

Tags: coordinate-transformation, rotational-matrices

Given an arbitrary 4x4 transformation matrix, how do I find out the center of rotation?

```
m = [m11 m12 m13 m14; 
     m21 m22 m23 m24;
     m31 m32 m33 m34; 
     m41 m42 m43 m44]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that `m` is purely a rotation matrix, and not the aggregation of multiple transformations of different types, you can find the axis of rotation (vector `v`) by solving the following equation:

```
mv = v
```

This works because rotating a vector about itself does not change the vector. (Note there are multiple solutions to this equation, but they all differ only by a scalar factor.)

Unfortunately, if you cannot be sure that `m` does not include other transformations, I don't know if you can find the axis of the rotation, or even if there is a unique axis of rotation to be found.

Comment: I know that `m = Translation * Rotation`.
Is there a solution to that problem?

Comment: Yes! m14, m24, and m34 represent the three components of the translation, so you can zero those out, and you will have a pure rotation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

> Given an arbitrary 4x4 transformation matrix, how do I find out the center of rotation?

The problem cannot be solved in general case, because matrix might not represent rotation. It could be projection matrix, zero matrix, etc.

Aside from that you might want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9918735/271376).

Your matrix represents transform that converts old coordinate system into new coordinate system.

---

Object matrix can be represented this way:

```
objx.x     objx.y     objx.z    0 //m[0][0]..m[0][3] or _11, _12, _13, _14
objy.x     objy.y     objy.z    0 //m[1][0]..m[1][3] or _21, _22, _23, _24
objz.x     objz.y     objz.z    0 //m[2][0]..m[2][3] or _31, _32, _33, _34
objpos.x   objpos.y   objpos.z  1 //m[3][0]..m[3][3] or _41, _42, _43, _44
```

Where m[][] and _11.._44 are corresponding elements of D3DMATRIX, objpos - object position vector, objx - object x ('local x" transformed to world space) vector, etc.

So as long as the last column (m[0..3][3]) is 0, 0, 0, 1 you can extract object position and its "x", "y", "z" vectors ("side", "up", "front" - which is which depends on application) from matrix. If last column is not "0, 0, 0, 1", then it is projection matrix and you can't extract object data from it this easily.

---

So you can extract individual vector and center of old coordinate system within new coordinate system, and individual vectors. THen you can find out center of rotation or whatever you want using them.

However, for a matrix to represent rotation, following must be true:

1. dotProduct(objx, objy) == 0
2. dotProduct(objx, objz) == 0
3. dotProduct(objx, objz) == 0
4. dotProduct(objx, objx) == 1
5. dotProduct(objy, objy) == 1
6. dotProduct(objz, objz) == 1
7. Last column is [0, 0, 0, 1]

And individual axes should be properly oriented (so you can be sure this isn't a "mirror" matrix). Exact orientation depends on your application. Could be something like this:

1. crossProduct(objy, objx) == objz
2. crossProduct(objx, objz) == objy
3. crossProduct(objz, objy) == objx

Comment: 2nd and 3rd statements are the same:
dotProduct(objx, objz) == 0